# Select2 dropdown is not working properly in Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown, html-select

I'm trying to place select2 dropdown in my popover - select2 dropdown is rendering normally when I open popover for the first time, but if I close it and open again - it renders 2 select2 dropdowns, one of which is unclickable:

[image: 2 select2 dropdowns]

I've already tried `z-index` solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561233/select2-doesnt-work-on-bootstrap-popover-form) and the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772705/select-2-with-bootstrap-popover), and they didn't work.
I've also read that select2 doesn't work properly in Bootstrap modal's and also tried to render it with `dropdownParent` property - didn't work too.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="actions-row mb-5">
   <button type="button" class="btn popover-toggle add-to-program-popover" data-placement="bottom">
   Add to program
   </button>
   <div class="program-container" style="display: none">
      <select name="movement-program-select" class="movement-program-select">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="Program 1">Program 1</option>
         <option value="Program 2">Program 2</option>
         <option value="Program 3">Program 3</option>
      </select>
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o add-to-program" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <hr>
      <a class="create-new-program">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o add-item"></i>
      Create new program</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**This is my JS code:**

```
 $('button.add-movement-to-program').on('click', function(e) {
   $('.add-to-program-table-container').show();
 });

 $('button.add-to-program-popover').popover({
   container: 'main',
   html: true,
   content: function() {
     return $('.program-container').html();
   }
 });

 $('button.add-to-program-popover').click(function() {
  // console.log(1);
  // if (!$('.movement-program-select').hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
  // console.log(2);
  $('.movement-program-select').select2({
    container: 'body',
    width: "100%",
    dropdownParent: $('.popover-content')
  });
  // }
});
```

Are there any other variants on how it can be fixed?

**Here is a link to my JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/fpk047rh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [show event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers-events) to target the `select` element inside your popover.

Here's an example

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="myButton" class="btn btn-lg">Click to toggle popover</button>
  <div id="form" style="display:none;">
    <select class="select-program" name="program">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Program 1">Program 1</option>
      <option value="Program 2">Program 2</option>
      <option value="Program 3">Program 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="add-program"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  $("#myButton").popover({
    html: true,
    content: $("#form").html(),
    placement: "bottom"
  });

  $("#myButton").on("show.bs.popover", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(".popover-content .select-program")
        .select2({
          dropdownParent: $(".popover-content")
        })
        .on("select2:select", function (e) {
          var data = e.params.data;
          $(".popover-content .add-program").html("Add " + data.text);
        });
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

More information can be found [here](https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement).

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/CraftedPod/pen/ZEbwWjd?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with `inserted.bs.popover` event:

```
$('button.add-to-program-popover').popover({
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('.program-container').html();
  }
});

$('button.add-to-program-popover').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
  $('div.popover-content select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('.popover-content')
  });
});
```

Also, the select box that I'm transforming to select2 dropdown is the one that is inside popup container (`$('div.popover-content select')`)